# Button create whith JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Who is wrong. I will create two buttons, one with html, another jQuery. When I clicked "HTML creat" displays the message and creates a button. When I clicked "jQuery creat displays the message. But when I clicked the newly created "My Button" button in the message is not

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    function appendText() {
      var button = $("<button>My Button</button>");
      $('p').append(button);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.<br></p>
<div>
   <button onclick="appendText()">HTML creat</button>
</div>
<script>
    var button = $("<button>JQuery creat</button>");
    $('div').append(button);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The new `button` has no listener attached to it, so what should happen?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach events with dynamically created elements. You can delegate event to closest parent of button or document.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on("click", "button", function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));    
     });
});
```

Delegate event to parent div, it would be better if you assign id or class to parent div and use id or class selector to delegate event.

```
$('div').ready(function () {
     $(document).on("click", "button", function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));    
     });
});
```

Comment: Prefer using `delegate`over `on`

Comment: @TejaKantamneni You should only be using delegate if you are on `-1.7`. `.on` supersedes `.delegate` as of `1.7`

Comment: @TejaKantamneni OP is using jQuery version 1.9 and as of jQuery 1.7 `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document)on('click', 'button', function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));

    });
});
```

Raw js (ie8 not considered):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        if(e.target.tagName === 'button'){
              alert(e.target.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The "JQuery Create" button doesn't add the button since you've never called the appendText() function... I've removed the direct call from the "My Button" button and added the appendText call into the click binding function.

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    function appendText() {
      var button = $("<button>My Button</button>");
      $('p').append(button);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
            appendText();

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.<br></p>
<div>
   <button>HTML create</button>
</div>
<script>
    var button = $("<button>JQuery create</button>");
    $('div').append(button);
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    function appendText() {
      var button = $("<button>My Button</button>");
      $('p').append(button);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "button", function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));    
 });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.<br></p>
<div id="myDiv">
   <button onclick="appendText()">HTML creat</button>
</div>
<script>
    var button = $("<button onclick='appendText()'>JQuery creat</button>");
    $('#myDiv').append(button);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Dont be so rude, i'm still learning...tested on localhost; the new generated button have make an alert when clicked.

Saludos ;)

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why.

Comment: I append the Jquery creat button to the div id = "myDiv" and added the onclick function call appendText....and in the appendText function i change the button click by this piece of code $(document).on("click", "button", function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));    
 }); ....the document.on do the trick....i'm spanish, sorry for miss the explanation part ;)

Answer (score 0):

The document.ready function is called after the document is ready.

1 - When your document is finished there is no button "My Button" so none of them will be binded with the event listener.

To do what you want, you have to bind the listener when you create the button, something like this:

```
var button = $("<button>My Button</button>");
button.click(function () {
     alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
$('p').append(button);
```

2 - Besides your jQuery listener to click is overwriting the onclick property of the element. To avoid that in a flexible way and call them both, add this to you click listener

```
eval($(this).attr("onclick"));
```

You can check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hFqBU/) to see those thing working.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the problem is how you bind the `.click` event. Before jQuery 1.7 they had separate methods for `.bind`, `.delegate` and `.live`. But with arrival of jQuery 1.7 these methods were merged an to simplify things by including them all under 1 method `.on`. But due to not so clear documentation people don't understand the `.on` method. `.on` does provide the function of 3 above mentioned deprecated methods, but it depends how you use `.on` method. Here is an example:

```
// Bind
$( "button" ).on( "click", function( e ) {} ); 

// Live
$( document ).on( "click", "button", function( e ) {} );

// Delegate
$( "body" ).on( "click", "button", function( e ) {} );
```

My guess is that markup for the `button` that is not working is being declared after your `.click` is bind. In that case you will have to implement the `.on` as done for live events. So all you would need to change is the way you bind call.

```
$( document ).on( "click", "button", function () {
        //Do Something
});
```

Hope this helps.